# Preciso verificar se uma linha está duplicada no meu TXT como faço?

Tags: php

Preciso verificar se uma linha está duplicada no meu `TXT` como faço?

---

```
<?php
$divisao = "1000000000000";
$linha  = file("clientes/clientes.txt"); //Abre o banco de dados
$total  = count($linha); //Conta as linhas
$paginas = ceil($total/$divisao)-1; //Faz a divisão

if(!$pagina='$pagina;' ){$pagina = "0";}
else if(!is_numeric($pagina)){$pagina = "0";}
else if($pagina > $paginas){$pagina = "0";}
else{$pagina = $pagina;}
if($total<=0){
    echo "<P><DIV style=\"font-family:arial; font-size:14px; color:#999; text-align:center; margin-left:0 auto;\">Sem clientes para exibir!</DIV>";
}


$inicio = $pagina*$divisao;
$final  = $inicio+$divisao;
$final  = ($final > $total) ? $total : $final;
$linha = array_reverse($linha);
for ($i = $inicio; $i < $final; $i++){
list($dado1,$dado2,$dado3,$dado4,$dado5,$dado6) = explode("|",$linha[$i]);
echo "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"form.php\" onSubmit=\"if(!confirm('Deseja realmente continuar o pedido?')){return false;}\">";
echo "<tr><td>";

echo "<div id=\"div-clientes\">";


echo "<span style=\"display:none;\">$dado2</span>";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"id\" value=\"$dado1\" id=\"campo_cads_id\" readonly=\"true\">";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"data\" value=\"$dado6\" id=\"campo_cads_data\" readonly=\"true\">";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"telefone\" value=\"$dado2\" id=\"campo_cads_tel\">";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"nome\" value=\"$dado3\" id=\"campo_cads\">";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"endereco\" value=\"$dado4\" id=\"campo_cads_end\">";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"referencia\" value=\"$dado5\" id=\"campo_cads\">";

?>
```

> Exemplo dos dados contidos no txt

```
DADO1|DADO2|DADO3|DADO4|DADO5|DADO6|
DADO1|DADO2|DADO3|DADO4|DADO5|DADO6|
DADO1|DADO2|DADO3|DADO4|DADO5|DADO6|
```

Preciso que verifique exemplo o `dado2` com o `dado2` da próxima linha e dizer se está duplicado?

Comment: Se tentou algum código?

Comment: Por exemplo aqui você ler o arquivo https://imasters.com.br/artigo/1134/php/php-lendo-um-arquivo-txt?trace=1519021197&source=single

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Tenho um BD em txt como verifico se algum dado armazenado está duplicado e exibilo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/255079/tenho-um-bd-em-txt-como-verifico-se-algum-dado-armazenado-est%c3%a1-duplicado-e-exibi)

Comment: Meu código jáestá listando o txt assim dados assim list($dado1,$dado2,$dado3,$dado4,$dado5,$dado6) e dentro do txt assim: dado1 | dado2 | dado3 | dado4 | dado5 | dado6 |

Comment: faltou o exemplo do arquivo!?

Comment: DADO1|DADO2|DADO3|DADO4|DADO5|DADO6|

Comment: Colo um exemplo com 3 linhas (na pergunta) e uma repetindo e é pra fazer o que quando repetir? (Veja a pergunta tem que possui detalhes mais aprofundados) até posso te ajudar a partir disso.

Comment: Editei a pergunta coloquei o exemplo! Desculpe éporque sou novo neste fórum!

Comment: @Rafa é só o dado2 ou seja só verificar na segunda coluna ?

Comment: Sim amigo só o dado2

Comment: Eu consegui fazer para verificar se exite o dado2 mas eu queria para ver se esta duplicado entende?

Comment: vc pode utilizar o in_array($dado, $array) e verificar se o dado se encontra no array, mas a coisa a meu ver já tem erro técnico quando o cara comenta "abre o BANCO DE DADOS" com o fopen de arquivo... vc sabe que se o seu site estiver on, até pelo google da pra achar o seu "banco de dados" né?

Comment: Eu estou utilizando em local host para cadastro de clientes de uma pizzaria, com isso só eu tenho acesso! Mas como utilizo esta função que você citou?

Comment: Entendo é só criar um novo array e varrer a lista somatizando.

Comment: Como faço isso amigo pode fazer o código pra mim?

Comment: ???????????????

Answer (score 2):

Função in_array(variavel, array) tem por objetivo verificar se o objeto está contido na array, como o nome diz ele verifica se o valor está no array. Irá retornar true ou false, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php
$people = array("Peter", "Joe", "Glenn", "Cleveland");

if (in_array("Glenn", $people))
  {
  echo "Encontrado";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Não encontrado";
  }
?>
```

Neste caso, Glenn está no array, então ele entrará no primeiro if. Mais dúvidas a documentação oficial:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp

PS: Dùvidas como esta são facilmente sanadas em outras perguntas já feitas aqui no grupo. Antes de postar leia a documentação

Para pesquisar como um todo faz isso:

```
if(strpos(file_get_contents("texto.txt"),$string)) {
    echo "tem";
}else{
    echo "não tem";
}
```

Comment: vc vai colocar ele num array 'picando' cada linha num array de linha ou se ele for só um elemento da linha voce pode fazer o explode pelo espaço (" "), ali em cima, te ensinei a fazer a comparação do array com a variável, agora vai descobrir como colocar o valor isolado nos valores do array

Comment: coloquei a opção 2 com carinho!

Comment: ia deixar vc conhecer o in_array antes de descobrir o jeito fácil, mas to de extremo bom humor hj!

Comment: no final do código eu coloquei um código que busca todo o arquivo TXT atrás de uma variável... se houver a variável ele retorna um true, se nao retorna um false, outra alternativa seria vc contar com +1 cada vez que ele aparece e verificar o valor no final. Os métodos e os formatos são estes... vc pode aplicá-los como lhe for melhor.

Comment: poxa! vai dar uma estudada, velho...

Comment: ajudar nao é fazer pra voce. te dei 2 caminhos, expliquei como fazer, dei o passo a passo, mastiguei, agora é com voce!

Comment: @Rafa como o Michel referiu este site não é para fazer o trabalho por outros. É para ajudar a aprender e resolver problemas. É importante perceberes isso para te integrares melhor na comunidade.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar este código para ler o arquivo `.txt` linha por linha verificando as ocorrências em cada linha:

```
<?php
$dado2 = "DADO2";

$arquivo = file("teste.txt");
$encontrar = $dado2;
$repetido = false;

if ($arquivo !== false)
{
    foreach($arquivo as $index => $line)
    {
         if (preg_match("/$encontrar/", trim($line), $matches))
        {
            if($repetido){
               echo 'A linha '. ($index+1) .' contém repetido '.$encontrar . '<br />';
            }else{
               echo 'A linha '. ($index+1) .' contém '.$encontrar . '<br />';
            }
            $repetido = true;
        }
    }
}
?>
```